# Getting 501 Server Error: Not Implemented error when trying to backup Firebase from a remote server

Tags: python, firebase

I have a Python script that pulls backup of the Firebase db and saves it to the server. I am able to execute it successfully from my machine, however, when I run it from [`pythoneverywhere`](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) server, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "somescript.py", line 58, in <module>
    data = json.dumps(f.get('/', None), sort_keys = False, indent = 4)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebase/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebase/firebase.py", line 274, in get
    return make_get_request(endpoint, params, headers, connection=connection)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebase/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebase/firebase.py", line 42, in make_get_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 638, in raise_for_status
    raise http_error
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 501 Server Error: Not Implemented

2015-03-17 15:01:12 -- Completed task, took 4.00 seconds, return code was 1.
```

Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
def connect_firebase(configs):
    firebaseUrl = configs.get('Firebase', 'ProdFirebaseURL')
    firebaseSecret = configs.get('Firebase', 'FirebaseSecret')

    f = firebase.FirebaseApplication(firebaseUrl, None)
    f.authentication = firebase.FirebaseAuthentication(firebaseSecret, "", admin=True)
    return f

...

f = connect_firebase(config)
data = json.dumps(f.get('/', None), sort_keys = False, indent = 4) #busts here
```

*Same* script with *same* params was running fine on `pythoneverywhere` server a few weeks ago. I have reinstalled `requests 1.1.0` and `python-firebase` using `pip` on both my machine and the server and am still able to access it from my machine but not from `pythoneverywhere` server. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Just to clarify, it now does not work on both your local machine or on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: Clarified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by uninstalling `requests 1.1.0` lib from the server. Still no idea what was wrong, since `Firebase` folks [advise](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2) to install that library prior to installing `Firebase`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get past the authentication part, then the connection should be getting through/it isn't a proxy problem.

Maybe double check your `ProdFirebaseURL` is correct?
And double check that the `'/'` that you are calling `f.get()` on is a valid end point?

I would try doing `f.get(<the-full-url>)` just to double check/make sure.

Comment: And how does this explain exact same code with exact same params working on all other machines?

Comment: Well when you say everything is the same, can you instead list how the two environments differ? I'm assuming certain files, access tokens, env var files etc might be manually copied or may need new sets generated. Maybe even diff os/firebase versions